# kotlin string helpers to find index in a string where any element of another string matches first/last etc

Tags: kotlin

C++ has string functions like `find_first_of()`, `find_first_not_of()`, `find_last_of()`,
`find_last_not_of()`. e.g. if I write

```
string s {"abcdefghi"};
```

- `s.find_last_of("eaio")` returns the index of i
- `s.find_first_of("eaio")` returns the index of a
- `s.find_first_not_of("eaio")` returns the index of b

Does Kotlin has any equivalent.

Comment: @Sweeper You are right. Thanks for pinpointing the mistake. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin doesn't have these exact functions, but they are all special cases of [`indexOfFirst`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/index-of-first.html) and [`indexOfLast`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/index-of-last.html):

```
fun CharSequence.findFirstOf(chars: CharSequence) = indexOfFirst { it in chars }
fun CharSequence.findLastOf(chars: CharSequence) = indexOfLast { it in chars }
fun CharSequence.findFirstNotOf(chars: CharSequence) = indexOfFirst { it !in chars }
fun CharSequence.findLastNotOf(chars: CharSequence) = indexOfLast { it !in chars }
```

These will return -1 if nothing is found.

Usage:

```
val s = "abcdefghi"
val chars = "aeiou"
println(s.findFirstOf(chars))
println(s.findFirstNotOf(chars))
println(s.findLastOf(chars))
println(s.findLastNotOf(chars))
```

Output:

```
0
1
8
7
```